# Python3 - Tkinter - Instant messaging

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I made a simple chat program in python that uses tkinter and mysql db. It connects to db first, gets the messages and shows them to user. But when another user send a message to the user, the user can not see the new messages. So, I made a refresh button. But, everybody knows, people don't want to use a chat program that you always should press a button to see messages. The question is, how can I make a instant message app without clicking any buttons?

- It doesn't require to use tkinter for gui. It can be run with other gui libs.

Comment: To make something happen periodically in a Tkinter application, such as checking the server for new messages, use [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method).

Comment: Might be worth posting some code.

Answer (score 0):

in order to periodically refresh the user messages, just make an infinite while loop and set it to update every 5 seconds or so. this way every 5 seconds you check to see if database has new messages. alternatively you can make the while loop update if the database has been updated at any point but this is more complex.